# Echo nlb2r htmlspecialchar

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars, nl2br

Want to use nl2br and htmlspecialchar. Right now result will say nl2br before the content.

```
     $contentfix = wordwrap($content, 100, "<br />\n", true);

     echo '<div style="color:white;font-size:20px;/*font-family:play ;">'.nl2br 
    ,htmlspecialchars ($contentfix, ENT_QUOTES).'</div> ';
```

Comment: What is your question? Note that you have an _"Use of undefined constant nl2br"_ notice, and unclosed comment in the `style` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly: you can't call functions comma-seperated.
Secondly: you have an unclosed multiline comment.

Try this:

```
$contentfix = wordwrap($content, 100, "<br />", true);
echo '<div style="color:white; font-size:20px;">'. nl2br(htmlspecialchars($contentfix, ENT_QUOTES)) . '</div>';
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. My code is kinda cluttered and will clean it up later. Just trying to get the primary functions to work. Thanks for pointing out that comment I had no clue I had there.